# Adding a new registry file through batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I've been trying to add a new registry key and it's been working fine, noting the fact that this addition is not going to harm my computer it's just for me to understand a few concepts. The problem that's been happening is as follows, when I run my batch file, it's displaying the following message in cmd:

```
 off REG ADD HKLM\Software\Hello - 24919 /v Test /t REG_BINARY /d fe340ead
```

the "off" in bold is a little weird, I'm not sure what happened for it to appear and not add the key, like I said I'm using batch commands and basically writing to another batch file through my initial batch file and this is the code I used:

```
@echo off
set new=new2.bat
echo @echo off REG ADD HKLM\Software\Hello - %random% /v Test /t REG_BINARY /d fe340ead    >>%new%
```

Help is appreciated please! and thank you!

PS: I've referred to the following question ([adding a random key to the registry through a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956912/adding-a-random-key-to-the-registry-through-a-batch-file#)) , and did exactly the same, it worked once but then I don't know what happened for the above to show and not add the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set new=new2.bat
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo ^>nul REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Hello - %random%" /v Test /t REG_BINARY /d fe340ead
) > %new%
```

You need to place the `@echo off` and the `REG ADD` in separate lines

Comment: If i were to hide the output to nul where shall I add the "> nul" command?

Comment: @Scarl. Answer updated. To `echo` the special character `>`, it needs to be escaped.